# Get firebase functions instance id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

As I understand, firebase functions execute in the *Google Functions Execution Environment*.

This means that functions are executed in a single instance. According to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec):

> A new function instance is only started in two cases:
>
> 1. When you deploy your function
> 2. When a new function instance is automatically created to scale up to the load, or occasionally to replace an existing instance.

My question is:

Is it possible to get this instance id, inside firebase functions?

Comment: just wondering whats you are going to do with instance id?

Comment: I would add it to logging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no formally exposed instance ID.  Normally it would not matter which instance is running your code, and your code shouldn't depend on running in a particular instance

If you need to tag a particular instance for some reason, you could generate your own [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and store it in a global variable.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I completely agree that the code shouldn't  depend on running in a particular instance, but you know - when you are debugging a failing function the more information the better. The UUID is a good solution, thanks :)